# Implementing 2D slicing in Python

Tags: python, duck-typing

I'm implementing a linear algebra library in Python (I know something probably exists, but I'm doing it to learn about Python and the maths I need for my exams), and I want to be able to access elements/subsets of a matrix like so:

(My matrix class is a subclass of tuple.)

- `M = Matrix([list of rows of elements])`
- `M[1, 2]` Gets element at (1, 2)
- `M[3]` Gets row 3

These are pretty easy to do, but I also want to implement slicing, like so:

- `M[:,:]` returns the entire matrix
- `M[1:6:2]` returns the rows 1, 3 and 5
- `M[1:6:2, 0:2]` returns a matrix consisting of rows 1, 3 and 5 intersected with the first two columns.

I have done this, but my answer seems very un-pythonic:

```
def __getitem__ (self, idx):
    if isinstance(idx, numbers.Integral):
        # Code to return the row at idx
    elif (isinstance(idx, tuple) and len(idx) == 2 and
            all(isinstance(i, numbers.Integral) for i in idx)):
        # Code to return element at idx
    elif (isinstance(idx, tuple) and len(idx) == 2 and
            all(isinstance(i, slice) for i in idx)):
        # Code to parse slices
```

The other problem with this is that both indices have to be numbers, or slices, I can't mix. To do it this way would require two more elif blocks, and that seems like two many. Already the code is really ugly.

I think the answer involves duck typing, but I'm not completely sure how to implement that. I've been looking at `try:except:` blocks, but I'm not sure how to chain those, and I don't really want to nest too much.

So, SO, thank you for reading. What is the best way to implement a function like this?

Comment: PS, once you finish building this yourself, go look at [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org), the most prominent something that already exists. It does everything you want and more, and will likely make your code a little easier to read and a whole lot faster. I didn't want to mention that right away, because I didn't want to discourage you from having fun coming up with your own designs… but I also want to make sure you don't miss out on the fun of playing with `numpy`.

Comment: No, I know about numpy. Haven't used it yet, since I've only been writing Python for about three days. That said, it's about all I've been doing. I'm pursuing a Mathematics degree, so I'm bent towards that, though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pretty much have to do *something* like this… but at least you can remove some duplication.

First, it's probably reasonable to consider `[1,]` to mean "row 1", just like `[1]`. (`numpy` does this.) That means you don't need the tuple-vs.-int thing; just treat an int as a 1-element tuple. In other words:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if isinstance(idx, numbers.Integral):
        idx = (idx, slice(None, None, None))
    # now the rest of your code only needs to handle tuples
```

Second, although your sample code only handles the case of two slices, your real code has to handle two slices, or a slice and an int, or an int and a slice, or two ints, or a slice, or an int. If you can factor out the slice-handling code, you don't need to duplicate it over and over again.

One trick for handling int-vs.-slice is to treat `[n]` as a wrapper that does, in essence, `[n:n+1][0]`, which lets you reduce everything even more. (It's a tiny bit trickier than this, because you have to special-case either negative numbers in general, or just `-1`, because obviously `n[-1] != n[-1:0][0]`.) For 1-D arrays this may not be worth it, but for 2D arrays it probably is, because it means while you're dealing with the column, you've always got a list of rows rather than just a row.

On the other hand, you may want to share some code between `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`… which makes some of these tricks either impossible or a lot harder. So, there's a tradeoff.

At any rate, here's an example that does all the simplification and pre/postprocessing I could think of (possibly more than you want) so that ultimately you're always looking up a pair of slices:

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.m = [[row + col/10. for col in range(4)] for row in range(4)]
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, (numbers.Integral, slice)):
            idx = (idx, slice(None, None, None))
        elif len(idx) == 1:
            idx = (idx[0], slice(None, None, None))
        rowidx, colidx = idx
        rowslice, colslice = True, True
        if isinstance(rowidx, numbers.Integral):
            rowidx, rowslice = slice(rowidx, rowidx+1), False
        if isinstance(colidx, numbers.Integral):
            colidx, colslice = slice(colidx, colidx+1), False
        ret = self.m[rowidx][colidx]
        if not colslice:
            ret = [row[0] for row in ret]
        if not rowslice:
            ret = ret[0]
        return ret
```

Or it might be nicer if you refactored things along the other axis: Get the row(s), and then get the column(s) within it/them:

```
def _getrow(self, idx):
    return self.m[idx]

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if isinstance(idx, (numbers.Integral, slice)):
        return self._getrow(idx)
    rowidx, colidx = idx
    if isinstance(rowidx, numbers.Integral):
        return self._getrow(rowidx)[colidx]
    else:
        return [row[colidx] for row in self._getrow(rowidx)]
```

This looks a whole lot simpler, but I'm cheating here by forwarding the second index to the normal `list`, which only works because my underlying storage is a `list` of `list`s. But if you have *any* kind of indexable row object to defer to (and it doesn't waste unacceptable time/space to create those objects unnecessarily), you can use the same cheat.

---

If you're objecting to the need to type-switch on the index parameter, yes, that does seem generally unpythonic, but unfortunately it's how `__getitem__` generally works. If you want to use the usual EAFTP `try` logic, you can, but I don't think it's more readable when you have to try two different APIs (e.g., `[0]` for tuples, and `.start` for slices) in multiple places. You end up doing "duck-type-switching" up at the top, like this:

```
try:
    idx[0]
except AttributeError:
    idx = (idx, slice(None, None, None))
```

… and so on, and this is just twice as much code as normal type-switching without any of the usual benefits.

Comment: Beautiful, I was actually quite close to your second answer with what I had; thank you very much. I don't have to worry about __setitem__, or internal storage methods, because I am inheriting from tuple. (I wrote a vector class also, my matrix is an embellished tuple of vectors, which are also embellished tuples.)

Comment: Using a 1D (N*M-length) tuple as the internal storage is definitely reasonable, but you might want to consider encapsulating and delegating instead of inheriting.